# Good way to run keyframes animation when element comes into view?

Tags: javascript, css, css-animations

What is a good way to run keyframes animation when an element comes into view?

```
$(window).scroll(function () {
  if($(window).scrollTop() > 0) {
    element.addClass("animateMe");
  }
  else {
    element.removeClass("animateMe");
  }
});
```

This code works, but it needs a static number, which is bad for adaptive layouts.

Answer (score 0):

Console.log() will be triggered when box is viewed on screen

```
        var pageTop  = $(window).scrollTop();
        var pageBottom =  pageTop + $(window).height()

        var eleTop = $(".box").offset().top;
        var eleBottom = eleTop +  $(".box").height();

        //only if ele is view on screen     
        if(pageBottom >= eleTop && eleBottom >= pageTop){
               console.log("viewed.....");
        }
```